# A fast method to add a label column to large pd dataframe based on a range of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm fairly new to python and am working with large dataframes with upwards of 40 million rows. I would like to be able to add another 'label' column based on the value of another column.

if I have a pandas dataframe (much smaller here for detailing the problem)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#using random to randomly get vals (as my data is not sorted)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,1000),columns = ['col1'])
```

I then have another dictionary containing ranges associated with a specific label, similar to something like:

```py
my_label_dict ={}
my_label_dict['label1'] = np.array([[0,10],[30,40],[50,55]])
my_label_dict['label2'] =  np.array([[11,15],[45,50]])
```

Where any data in my_df should be 'label1' if it is between 0,10 or 30,40 or 50,55
And any data should be 'label2' if it between 11 to 15 or 45 to 50.

I have only managed to isolate data based on the labels and retrieve an index through something like:

```py
idx_save = np.full(len(my_label_dict['col1']),False,dtype = bool).reshape(-1,1)

for rng in my_label_dict['label1']:
    idx_temp  = np.logical_and( my_label_dict['col1']> rng[0], my_label_dict['col1'] < rng[1]
    idx_save = idx_save | idx_temp
```

and then use this index to access label1 values from my_dict. and then repeat for label2.

Ideally I would like to add another column on my_label_dict named 'labels' which would add 'label1' for all datapoints that satisfy the given ranges etc. Or just a quick method to retrieve all values from the dataframe that satisfy the ranges in the labels.

I'm new to generator functions, and havent completely gotten my head around them but maybe they could be used here?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to the task in a "more pandasonic" way.

Start from creating a *Series*, named *labels*, initially with empty strings:

```
labels = pd.Series([''] * 100).rename('label')
```

The length is 100, just as the upper limit of your values.

Then fill it with proper labels:

```
for key, val in my_label_dict.items():
    for v in val:
        labels[v[0]:v[1]+1] = key
```

And the only thing to do is to merge your DataFrame with *labels*:

```
my_df = my_df.merge(labels, how='left', left_on='col1', right_index=True)
```

I also noticed such a contradiction in *my_label_dict*:

- you have *label1* for range between *50* and *55* (I assume inclusive),
- you have also *label2* for range between *45* and *50*,

so for value of *50* you have **two** definitions.

My program acts on the "last decision takes precedence" principle, so the label
for *50* is *label2*. Maybe you should change one of these range borders?

## Edit

A modified solution if the upper limit of *col1* is "unpredictable":

Define *labels* the following way:

```
rngMax = max(np.array(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    my_label_dict.values())))[:,1])
labels = pd.Series([np.nan] * (rngMax + 1)).rename('label')
for key, val in my_label_dict.items():
    for v in val:
        labels[v[0]:v[1]+1] = key
labels.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Add `.fillna('')` to `my_df.merge(...)`.

Comment: Thankyou! this is a lot faster than my current method!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that would also work for float ranges, where you can't create a mapping for all possible values. This solution requires resorting your dataframes.

```
# build a dataframe you can join and sort it for the from-field
join_df=pd.DataFrame({
        'from':  [ 0, 30, 50, 11, 45],
        'to':    [10, 40, 55, 15, 50],
        'label': ['label1', 'label1', 'label1', 'label2', 'label2']
    })
join_df.sort_values('from', axis='index', inplace=True)
# calculate the maximum range length (but you could alternatively set it to any value larger than your largest range as well)
max_tolerance=(join_df['to'] - join_df['from']).max()
# sort your value dataframe for the column to join on and do the join
my_df.sort_values('col1', axis='index', inplace=True)
result= pd.merge_asof(my_df, join_df, left_on='col1', right_on='from', direction='backward', tolerance=max_tolerance)
# now you just have to remove the lables for the rows for which the value passed the end of the range and drop the two range columns
result.loc[result['to']<result['col1'], 'label']= np.NaN
result.drop(['from', 'to'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

The `merge_asof(...direchtion='backward',...)` just joines for each row in `my_df` the row in `join_df` with the maximum value in `from` that still sattisfies `from<=col1`. It doesn't look at the `to` column at all. This is why we remove the labels where the `to` boundary is hurt by the assignment of np.NaN in the line with the `.loc`.